# Can I safely sign an APK for a third party?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, google-play

I'm developing an App for a third party. 
The client should receive an APK for him to manually upload to the Google Play Store.

For this, **I created a new Keystore**, and **saved the signed APK to disk**. Do I need to do anything else before sending the client the APK?

I'm asking this because for iOS I had to walkthrough the client to create and send me the appropriate certificates and private key for me to sign the .ipa file.

Is it this simple for Android? Or do I need to take additional steps into consideration?

Thank you

Comment: Has there been a version uploaded before? If yes, this is not going to work, it needs to be signed with the same keystore (or at least same info) every time. This also means, you will have to hand over the keystore if someone else is going to take over the development

Comment: No, this is a new App. So if I sign it myself, the client will be able to upload the APK with no issues? From what you are saying all I have to do is to make sure I don't loose the .keyinfo and .keystore files for future releases?

Comment: take a look at new changes implemented by google. Now you can store key within google play store https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Comment: I have issue related can anyone help please ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53459217/apk-that-is-not-signed-with-the-upload-certificate-google-play-store