# APK that is not signed with the upload certificate Google Play Store

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, google-play

I developed an app using Xamarin.Forms, and I would publish the app to Google Play Store, I generated the APK and Store key as the following document (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=windows) from Visual Studio, but when I upload the APK file to Google Play Store, I get the following error.

**Upload failed You uploaded an APK that is not signed with upload certificate. You must use the same certificate. The Upload certificate has  fingerprint...etc**

I have the old KeyStore but I lost the keyPassword

Comment: If you are trying to update an existing application on the store you must use the original(same) certificate.

Comment: Yes, I published the app since a year ago, and I would to upload a new version of the app to store, but I lost the old StoreKey, so I created a new one by Visual studio but the Upload process failed  @EvZ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to tell you the bad news, from the official [Android developer docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing):

> Ensure that the app signing key is not lost. Loss of the app signing
>   key means that an app cannot be updated, so it is critical for it not
>   to be lost.

**Update**
It seems like **Google now allow reseting certificates**. Please fill-in an issue on [this form](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/otherbugs). The operation may take a couple of business days.

Thanks @SushiHangover for pointing that out!

Comment: There no way to solve the issue? I have the old KeyStore but I lost the keyPassword?

Comment: You can have Google reset your upload cert by providing them with a new pem, it will take a few days, but they have allowed this since mid/late 2017 via submitting a help/issue ticket via Google Play Developer Support. Review the answers in the dup link for the process.